# prolog - check if item is somewhere on the right/left/between in a list

Tags: prolog

I have to figure out how to find out if the item is in between of two other items in the list. My thinking is that to have a `somewhereleft` and `somewhereright` functions and then use it in a way `somewherebetween(X,Y,Z,L) :- somewhereleft(X,Y,L), somewhereright(Y,Z,L)`. I have implemented function to find out if the item is to the right `right(X,Y, [X, Y|_]). right(X, Y, [_|T]) :-right(X, Y, T).` and to the left `left(X, Y, L) :- right(Y, X, L).`; however, cannot wrap my head around finding out the recursive `somewhereleft/right` functions.

Comment: What if `L = [c,b,a,b,c,b,a]` ? Should `somewherebetween(a,c,b, L)` succeed or fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**append/3** may be your friend

```
in_order(X, Y, Z, Lst) :-
    append(_, [X|T1], Lst),
    append(_, [Y|T2], T1),
    append(_, [Z|_], T2).
```

for example

```
?- in_order(a,b,c,[a,e,b,d,c]).
true .
```

but

```
?- in_order(a,b,c,[c,b,a,b,c,b,a]).
true ;
false.
```

Comment: it does what I need but could you give a quick explanation on why exactly does this work? I tried using `trace` but it was not too informative.

Comment: The first **append** finds in Lst a list beginning with X, we are only interested with the rest of the list, T1. The symbol '_' indicates that we are not interested by all the elements before X. The second **append** find in T1 a list beginning with Y, we are only interested with the rest T2, Finally we search a Z in T2, (we could have written member(Z, T2)).